# Descending sort of legend on power bi line chart

Tags: powerbi

Is there any way to do this without creating a custom column as I just want to reverse sort? I can't sort my legend in power bi line chart in descending order. I tried doing it in the source file after importing as well as in the model section but none seems to impact the visual. Line chart also does not have sort descending option when clicking on the three dots on top right corner.

Comment: Please post your code and what you've tried.

Comment: If you share screenshots in addition to code it can help in understanding the underlying issue.

Comment: This is probably a question for superuser.com